# Trying to connect to SQL Server on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a little silly program to test a Connection to a database on SQL Server 2014, I'm using c# on Visual Studio 2015.

First I tested it on my PC, it works wonderful! then I moved to my laptop. I did a little mistake while installing SQL 2014 because I installed the manager before installing the other Express version... but when I created the database It worked so I thought it was not a problem.

But when I tested the connection in my laptop it fails! every time I try, I started all SQL services, I created an string connection but in the field where is supposed to be the name of the server it doesn't displays anything. So I tried using "." as the name of the server and my database appeared, so I created the string connection and it says it is "connected".

I'm really desperate because it works perfectly on my PC but on my laptop it just fails.

Here is the code for the string, I have tested every name I see on SQL Server ( Julia, Julia-Fer, Julia\Fer, even .\SQLEXPRESS)

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn =
   new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        // TODO: Modify the connection string and include any
        // additional required properties for your database.
        conn.ConnectionString = "integrated security=SSPI;data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
 "persist security info=False;initial catalog=Proyecto";
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on PC and 2015 on my laptop.

Comment: The data source is supposed to be the name of the instance.  For a default instance, it will be just the machine name while, for a named instance, it will be machine name separated from the instance name by a backslash.  If the instance is on the same machine as the connecting client, you can substitute "." or "(local)" for the machine name.

Comment: It fails because....? what's the error?

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you so much for your explanation, after trying with the "." I put the Server Name like is seen on SQL Server on the Database Engine, I don't know why it didn't work before but Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string to be like

```
conn.ConnectionString = "data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Proyecto;persist security info=False;integrated security=true";
```